# Trouble displaying tableview in iOS with dynamic cells

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have an nslog that is successfully telling me that the information I will load into dynamic cells is there. However, I've discovered that my tableView is not loading the array "dogs" with object "dogs" at all because the nslog for name11Label is returning null despite the fact that there is a value for dogs in viewDidLoad. What would I need to do to initiate the tableView? (.h does have an iboutlet and a property(just to make sure) for my "tableView" and also has  as well as and import for cell11.h)

.m file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
...
     self.tableview.delegate = self;
...
}

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        if ( dogs != NULL ) {
            return [dogs count];
        }
        return 0;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       Cell11 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell11"];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[Cell11 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell11"] autorelease];  //I know that this method is depreciated, but it is not the source of this problem
        }
        NSDictionary *itemAtIndex =(NSDictionary *)[dogs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         cell.name11Label.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"dogs"];
         NSLog(@"dogs array = %@", dogs);   //returns correct information of the object dogs
         NSLog(@"%@", cell.name11Label.text);   //returning null even though "dogs" in viewDidLoad is showing a result;

         return cell;

    }
```

Cell11.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Cell11 : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *name11Label;

@end
```

Cell11.m

```
#import "Cell11.h"

@implementation Cell11
@synthesize name11Label;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Cell11 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell11"];
```

to

```
Cell11 *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell11"];
```

tableView is probably not hooked up right.

<strike>The nslog statement will never get called. Move it above:</strike>

```
NSLog(@"%@", cell.name11Label);
return cell;
```

Also you are initializing the cell with cgrect zero which won't display anything. Make sure it has a height and width that are expecting (e.g. CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f))

If the cell still doesn't display, are you calling reloadData on the tableview after the array dogs is set up?

Comment: Intersting. I didn't know that. Thanks. It has returned a null value. I will edit my question to reflect this new information.

Comment: you are calling [tableView reloadData] after you confirm that dogs[@"dogs"] is not null in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes I am. Is that a problem?

Comment: sorry no - it was meant to be a question, that is fine. Can you nslog dogs instead: NSLog(@"dogs array = %@", dogs)

Comment: Interestingly, the dogs array is showing having information...I've updated my code to show where I put it and the response.

Comment: can u show the output? Most likely this is not the right key: [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"dogs"];  Also your nslog should look like this: NSLog(@"%@", cell.name11Label.text);

Comment: 2012-11-09 16:44:58.074 dognameme[8203:c07] dogs array = (
        {
        dogs = "Black";
    }
)
2012-11-09 16:44:58.074 dognameme[8203:c07] (null) //this is for the cell.name11Label.text (after the nslog correction)

Comment: So, it is adding the item, but it is not correctly adding it to the custom text label...hmmm. I know that it is linked and that I am importing it into my .h file...I have updated my code with the custom cell information.

Comment: i would check cell.name11Label and make sure its hooked up/initialized correctly. That is probably also nil. Also make sure cell is not nil since its a custom cell.

Comment: I have the custom cell hooked up to the storyboard and I have the label hooked up to the storyboard label. I have imported it into my .h. Anything else I have to do to initialize it? I have posted the code above for you to see that it shouldn't be nil.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19356/discussion-between-edwin-iskandar-and-user1803649)

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned your UITableView's "dataSource" property to the object with the UITableViewDataSource protocol (the above methods)?

Comment: I have added     self.tableView.delegate = self; in the viewDidLoad and I have added in the .h file <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>. I've edited my question above to reflect those

Comment: Yeah, thats the problem. The delegate is for handling events such as didSelectRowAtIndeXPath. Set the dataSource also:

self.tableView.dataSource = self

Comment: Hmmm...I am getting a null still.

Comment: Can you post the initWithFrame method of Cell11?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You want me to post the custom cell code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: The NSLog after the return will never be called.

```
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.name11Label); 
    return cell;
}
```

Second: Control drag from you tableview of the interface builder to your class. And make sure the connection `dataSource` is properly connected.